# regex - how to recognise a pattern until a second one is found

Tags: python, regex

I have a file, named a particular way. Let's say it's:

```
tv_show.s01e01.episode_name.avi
```

it's the standard way a video file of a tv show's episode is named on the net. The pattern is quite the same all over the web, so I want to extract some information from a file named this way. Basically I want to get:

1. the show's title;
2. the season number `s01`;
3. the episode number `e01`;
4. the extension.

I'm using a Python 3 script to do so. This test file is pretty simple because all I have to do is this

```
import re

def acquire_info(f="tv_show.s01e01.episode_name.avi"):
    tvshow_title = title_p.match(f).group()
    numbers = numbers_p.search(f).group()
    season_number = numbers.split("e")[0].split("s")[1]
    ep_number = numbers.split("e")[1]
    return [tvshow_title, season_number, ep_number]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # re.I stands for the option "ignorecase"
    title_p = re.compile("^[a-z]+", re.I)
    numbers_p = re.compile("s\d{1,2}e\d{1,2}", re.I)
    print(acquire_info())
```

and the output is as expected `['tv_show', '01', '01']`. But what if my file name is like this other one? `some.other.tv.show.s04e05.episode_name.avi`.

How can I build a regex that gets all the text **BEFORE** the `"s\d{1,2}e\d{1,2}"` pattern is found?

P.S. I didn't put in the example the code to get the extension, I know, but that's not my problem so it does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
show_p=re.compile("(.*)\.s(\d*)e(\d*)")
show_p.match(x).groups()
```

where x is your string

Edit** (I forgot to include the extension, here is the revision)

```
show_p=re.compile("^(.*)\.s(\d*)e(\d*).*?([^\.]*)$")
show_p.match(x).groups()
```

---

And Here is the test result

```
>>> show_p=re.compile("(.*)\.s(\d*)e(\d*).*?([^\.]*)$")
>>> x="tv_show.s01e01.episode_name.avi"
>>> show_p.match(x).groups()
('tv_show', '01', '01', 'avi')
>>> x="tv_show.s2e1.episode_name.avi"
>>> show_p.match(x).groups()
('tv_show', '2', '1', 'avi')
>>> x='some.other.tv.show.s04e05.episode_name.avi'
>>> show_p.match(x).groups()
('some.other.tv.show', '04', '05', 'avi')
>>>
```

Comment: @Abhijit, nice code, but as soon as you run into something like `Ancient.Aliens.S06E17.The.Shamans.HDTV.x264-SPASM.mp4`, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option, use capturing groups to extract all of the info you want in one step:

```
>>> show_p = re.compile(r'(.*?)\.s(\d{1,2})e(\d{1,2})')
>>> show_p.match('some.other.tv.show.s04e05.episode_name.avi').groups()
('some.other.tv.show', '04', '05')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python expert but if it can do named captures, something general like this might work:

`^(?<Title>.+)\.s(?<Season>\d{1,2})e(?<Episode>\d{1,2})\..*?(?<Extension>[^.]+)$`

if no named groups, just use normal groups.

A problem could occur if the title has a `.s2e1.` part that masks the real season/episode part. That would require more logic. The regex above asumes that the title/season/episode/extension exists, and s/e is the farthest one to the right.